# Able to access UNC Path despite deleting all traces of credentials

Tags: windows-7, windows, network-shares

I'm trying to make Windows request for Credentials to access a UNC Share.
I'm trying to access the following share

**\\dhi-vm1\pictures**

The share can be accessed by "Everyone" which means Anybody with a valid user account on dhi-vm1. There's only one account on dhi-vm1 and it is "Administrator". So the only valid set of credentials is

**Username** : administrator
**Password** : password

I've accessed this share in the past with the above set of credentials but now I'd like to delete all traces of this on my machine. Here's what I've tried to accomplish this

- Delete the Credentials from Control Panel -> Credential Manager
- Run the following command "**NET USE * /DELETE"**

Despite running these commands I'm still able to access the share. How is it managing to do this ? 
I could reboot the machine and "fix" the issue but I need to know how its managing to access the share despite my best efforts for it not to.

Answer (score 1):

> The share can be accessed by "Everyone" which means Anybody with a
>   valid user account on dhi-vm1.

No, `Everyone` means literally *everyone*: [Well-known security identifiers in Windows operating systems](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/243330)

> **Name:** Everyone
>   **Description:** A group that includes all users, **even
>   anonymous users and guests**. Membership is controlled by the
>   operating system.

That's why you're able to use the share.

Comment: Does "Everyone" also include people who are trying to access a share on my machine (which is in domain1) from domain2 ?

Comment: @DhiwakarRavikumar Yes, see this article: [Understanding Groups](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd861330.aspx). Quote: `For example, the Everyone group is a special identity that represents all current network users, including guests and users from other domains.`